# Cannot linking cmake targets

Tags: cmake

I have the following structure of my project:

```
Project
-- CMakeLists.txt
-- src/
-- -- main.cpp
-- include/
-- -- curl/
-- -- -- *.h files
-- -- nlohmann/
-- -- -- *.hpp files
-- lib/
-- -- libcurl.lib
```

Project/CMakeLists:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
set(PROJECT_NAME "VKAPI")
project(${PROJECT_NAME} CXX)

include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

file(GLOB TARGET_SRC "./src/*.cpp")

add_executable(main ${TARGET_SRC})
target_link_libraries(main "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/libcurl.lib")

install(TARGETS main DESTINATION bin)
```

It works fine, but when I launch main.exe, it doesn't work. Instead of executing correctly and displaying the message, it ends with the code 0. Code:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "curl/curl.h"
#include "nlohmann/json.hpp"

int main()
{
    CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();

    std::cout << "That's work!" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Hello Easy C++ project!" << std::endl;
}
```

But when I delete `"#include "curl/curl.h""` and `"#include "nlohmann/json.hpp""`, it started to work fine.

Comment: Maybe this thread help [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16655705/cmake-cannot-determine-linker-language-for-target)

Comment: `TARGET_CURL "./*.h")` curl target has only headers. Headers don't mean much. So is this curl target a C++ or C project? Note that you are not linking _libraries_ but _cmake targets_.

Comment: @KamilCuk, it's a C++ project.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11801186/cmake-unable-to-determine-linker-language-with-c second asnwer

Comment: @KamilCuk, it did'nt help me.

Comment: No? Doing `set_target_properties(curl PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)` and similar for nlo-something should have worked.

Comment: @KamilCuk, it didn't help me too.
I decided to rewrite CMakeLists, check updates.

Comment: Please see the responses [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774593/cmake-link-to-external-library) for how to properly link external libraries using CMake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My error in the line: `target_link_libraries(main "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/libcurl.lib")`
It worked when I added a word `INTERFACE`: `target_link_libraries(main INTERFACE "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/libcurl.lib")`

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
file(GLOB TARGET_HEADERS "*.hpp")

add_library(nlohmann ${TARGET_HEADERS})
```

Is wrong in two ways:

1. You should not glob your sources,  you should list them explicitly.  There is plenty of guidance on this written already, globbing is a no-no in CMake.
2. Your "library" does not contain any source code.  A library in CMake requires source code such as a .c or .cpp file to compile.  You actually don't need to mention the header files at all, just tell CMake about the files it needs to compile, not the headers.

Comment: I suggest, I need to do next:
include_directories(./include/)
target_link_libraries(main "./lib/libcurl.lib")
and remove others cmakelists (curl & nlohmann)?

Comment: Yes, something like that.