# Can't determine link language for project

Tags: c++, cmake

I have this CMakeLists.txt file:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8)
CMAKE_POLICY(SET CMP0002 OLD)

PROJECT(gl_nbody C CXX)

ADD_EXECUTABLE(gl_nbody src/main.cpp)
set_target_properties(gl_nbody PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)

INCLUDE(FindPkgConfig)
PKG_SEARCH_MODULE(SDL2 REQUIRED sdl2)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(gl_nbody ${SDL2_LIBRARIES})

find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
include_directories(${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(gl_nbody ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES})

add_subdirectory("src")
add_subdirectory("include")
```

I'm not exactly sure what I am doing wrong.  I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11801186/cmake-unable-to-determine-linker-language-with-c) post.  However, the solutions posted have not solved my issue.  The output from cmake is:

```
-- Configuring done
CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target:gl_nbody
CMake Error: Cannot determine link language for target "gl_nbody".
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/jared/projects/gl_nbody
```

**Edit:** I have found that the issue is due to the CMakeLists.txt file in my *include* directory.  Here it is:

```
file(GLOB gl_nbody_HEADER 
    "*.h"   
)

#add_executable(gl_nbody ${gl_nbody_HEADER})
```

What is strange to me is that I have a similar file in my *src* directory whose only difference is that it adds .cpp files instead of .h files.  However, I get a link error when I try to add header files to my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`add_subdirectory` means add subdirectory which contain `CMakeLists.txt` file. When you need tell `CMake` about where your header files placed you need use `include_directory`:

```
include_directories (
    ${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include
)
```

Also I'd propose you merge and change some of directives in your files like this (I'm not sure about `FIND_PACKAGE` directives, but rest of directives in my opinion looks like correct):

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED (VERSION 2.8)
CMAKE_POLICY           (SET CMP0002 OLD)

FIND_PACKAGE      (OpenGL REQUIRED)
FIND_PACKAGE      (SDL    REQUIRED)

PROJECT (gl_nbody C CXX)

INCLUDE (FindPkgConfig)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES (
    ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include
)

SET (
    gl_nbody_SRS
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main.cpp
)

ADD_EXECUTABLE (
    gl_nbody
    ${gl_nbody_SRS}
)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES (
    gl_nbody
    ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES}
    ${SDL2_LIBRARIES}
)

SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES (
    gl_nbody
    PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX
)
```