# Build library using cmake for android with multiples .a files [CMake can not determine linker language for target]

Tags: android, c++, cmake

My target is build a library from a C++ SDK project.

I'm using this sample code as guide. [GoogleSamples/Android-NDK/Hello-Libs](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/840858984e1bb8a7fab37c1b7c571efbe7d6eb75/hello-libs)

And from this documentation, I can use more than one source: [add_library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_library.html)

Before I was using [set_target_properties](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/set_target_properties.html), but looks like don't need.

I'm getting the error `CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target: lib_llsdk`but this question about this error don't help [CMake unable to determine linker language with C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11801186/cmake-unable-to-determine-linker-language-with-c)

This is **my cmake** code:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)
set(distribution_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../llsdk)

add_library(lib_llsdk STATIC
${distribution_DIR}/libs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libins-sdk-simple-filter-    marker.a
${distribution_DIR}/libs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libopencv_aruco.a
${distribution_DIR}/libs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libopencv_calib3d.a
${distribution_DIR}/libs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libopencv_core.a
${distribution_DIR}/libs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libopencv_features2d.a
${distribution_DIR}/libs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libopencv_img_hash.a
${distribution_DIR}/libs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libopencv_imgproc.a
${distribution_DIR}/libs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libz.a)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=gnu++11")

add_library( native-lib
         SHARED
         src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp )


target_include_directories(native-lib PRIVATE
                       ${distribution_DIR}/include)


target_link_libraries(
                   native-lib
                   android
                  lib_lls
                  log)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just split and use set_target_properties

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

                   set(distribution_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../llsdk)

                   add_library(lib_llsdk_1 STATIC IMPORTED)
                   set_target_properties(lib_llsdk_1 PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
                       ${distribution_DIR}/libs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libins-sdk-simple-filter-marker.a)

                   add_library(lib_llsdk_2 STATIC IMPORTED)
                   set_target_properties(lib_llsdk_2 PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
                       ${distribution_DIR}/libs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libopencv_aruco.a)

                   add_library(lib_llsdk_3 STATIC IMPORTED)
                   set_target_properties(lib_llsdk_3 PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
                       ${distribution_DIR}/libs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libopencv_calib3d.a)

                   add_library(lib_llsdk_4 STATIC IMPORTED)
                   set_target_properties(lib_llsdk_4 PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
                       ${distribution_DIR}/libs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libopencv_core.a)

                   add_library(lib_llsdk_5 STATIC IMPORTED)
                   set_target_properties(lib_llsdk_5 PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
                       ${distribution_DIR}/libs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libopencv_features2d.a)

                   add_library(lib_llsdk_6 STATIC IMPORTED)
                   set_target_properties(lib_llsdk_6 PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
                       ${distribution_DIR}/libs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libopencv_img_hash.a)

                   add_library(lib_llsdk_7 STATIC IMPORTED)
                   set_target_properties(lib_llsdk_7 PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
                       ${distribution_DIR}/libs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libopencv_imgproc.a)

                   add_library(lib_llsdk_8 STATIC IMPORTED)
                   set_target_properties(lib_llsdk_8 PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
                       ${distribution_DIR}/libs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libz.a)

                   set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=gnu++11")


                   add_library( 
                                native-lib
                                SHARED
                                src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp )


                   target_include_directories(native-lib PRIVATE
                                              ${distribution_DIR}/include)

                   target_link_libraries(
                                          native-lib
                                          android
                                          lib_llsdk_1
                                          lib_llsdk_2
                                          lib_llsdk_3
                                          lib_llsdk_4
                                          lib_llsdk_5
                                          lib_llsdk_6
                                          lib_llsdk_7
                                          lib_llsdk_8
                                          log)
```